# Python: Acessing each frame within a while loop

Tags: python, psychopy

In Psychopy/Python: within a while loop, I need to read in some information (using pyserial) and append it to a list on every frame.

```
t = trialClock.getTime()
while True:

    line = ser.readline() #read in line
        if line:
        lines.append(line) #append to list

    ...
```

How can I access each frame using the trial clock? I need to read a line and append to the list every 0.016ms (60hz).

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a:

```
win.flip()
```

at the end of your code within the while loop so that the loop only iterates once per frame refresh. i.e. the code pauses at that point until the screen is actually redrawn, limiting your loop to 60 Hz (assuming your screen refreshes at that rate).

That way, you are using very precise hardware timing, rather than using a software timer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do have a win.flip() at the end, there is quite a lot of other stuff occurring after this part of the code, because of this I'm only appending to the list once every say 10 seconds or so. Do you know how I can append every 0.016?

Comment: I guess that means that the "lot of other stuff" can't be completed within 16 ms and might even be taking up to 10 s. Hence checking at 60 Hz won't be an option unless you completely restructure what you are doing, such as moving that code into a separate process (or use ioHub, which is designed to allow asynchronous hardware interfacing).